# How to deploy React client and Node server (Both in a single git repository) in Heroku?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, webpack

Am having a single Git repository where it contains both client and server.
This is my Webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.js"),
    module:{
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use:"babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use:['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js"
    }

}
```

So when I run `npm run Build` Its creating a single file bundle.js.
I placed bundle.js in the server static folder

```
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
    console.log('welcome')  
    res.send(req.sessionID)
})
```

in index.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        hello
        <script src='./bundle.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

if i try to start the node server. i cant see my browser serving the bundle.js am getting the below error

```
 Uncaught Error: Minified React error #200; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=200
```

If this is not the right approach, can anybody suggest a better so that i can deploy both my client and server code in heroku.

Comment: Did you look at what your error is in the url ?

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan I mentioned in the last line about the error. Is it possible to include bundle.js like a normal javascript file in html ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61497258/how-to-run-two-servers-in-heroku/61499366#61499366

Answer (score 0):

Considering your directory structure (DS) wasn't provided, the DS (in a MERN stack app) I find gives the least issues when deploying to Heroku is the following:

```
App (root)
|
|
+---client
|   |
|   +---src
|   +---...
|   +---package.json (react)
|
+---models
+---routes
+---package.json (node)
+---Procfile
+---server.js
```

Your package.json (node) scripts should look something like this (keeping other custom scripts):

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon server.js",
  "heroku-postbuild": "npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
}
```

Procfile should be:

```
web: node server.js
```

The package.json (react) scripts should stay relatively unchanged:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

}

I understand that you have customized a Webpack.config.js, bundle.js, and index.html, and that your app functionality has a particularly defined implementation - *for purposes of providing insight and potentially helping you reach a resolve*, here's what has worked and what continues to work for me...

In the server.js:

```
app.use("/", routes);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/client/build")));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

Notice that I'm declaring the use of my routes above, which has worked for me.

Hope this guides you...

Answer (score -1):

you can deploy them to separate Heroku dynos to deploy two apps.

More information regarding this is present in this [Deploy two separate heroku apps from same git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461517/deploy-two-separate-heroku-apps-from-same-git-repo/41466169#41466169)

> Note: It is always a good option to serve JS files from your API server after building React files.

Comment: 1. You absolutely can deploy completely unrelated non-web programs simultaneously as one program, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62529869/run-two-programs-off-the-same-procfile/62531358#62531358) - 2. It is possible to deploy a web client and web server simultaneously as one app on Heroku, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61497258/how-to-run-two-servers-in-heroku/61499366#61499366)